# in ESP32 / ESP-IDF - when to use EEPROM vs NVS vs SPIFFS?

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I'm fairly new to doing production work on ESP32 microcontrollers, and I'm wanting a little context and nuance from people who've been around the block a few times. So this question is a bit more on that kind of thing rather than a "how do I code X" kind of question.

I have lots of data storage needs on my current project.

- larger blobs of data that need to be stored less often
- smaller blobs of data that need to be updated more often
- factory settings (like serial number, board revision, etc) that are particular to a given device, but aren't going to be encoded in C.
- etc

I'm familiar with storing data in "blobs", and I'm familiar with encoding / decoding data with protocol buffers.

So given all that, I'm trying to gain context on the differences between my various storage options on the ESP32, and when to use each.

- EEprom
- NVS
- SPIFFS / LittleFS
- other options...

What use cases make you pick one of these options over another?

Comment: A tutorial can be https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/memory-types.html

Answer (score 14):

There's no EEPROM on the ESP32, just the flash.

[NVS](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/nvs_flash.html) is a simple non-volatile key-value store with different data types (integers 8-64 bits, strings, blobs). It's reasonably convenient to use, does wear levelling and supports flash encryption (although that a bit of a hassle). I'd use it for storing factory settings and anything else which is reasonably small (there's a 4000 byte limit on strings, 508,000 byte limit on blobs). If the device needs to write often, you might want to create a separate, dedicated, read-only NVS partition for storing device attributes (serial, hw info) so it's guaranteed to not get clobbered by power failures during write.

ESP IDF supports SPIFFS and FAT file systems.

[SPIFFS](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/spiffs.html#) is light-weight and much better in terms of wear levelling and reliability. I'd use this for storing any larger files. It doesn't support flash encryption, unfortunately.

[FAT](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/fatfs.html) file system is probably the worst choice because it's not really natively Flash-friendly, nor reliable. Espressif has built some kind of a layer between FAT and flash to accommodate wear levelling. The only critical advantage of FAT is that it supports flash encryption.

Then there are third party options which I haven't used, unfortunately.

As always, consider the number of page erases your writes are going to cause in the flash - this gives you an estimate of how many times you can write before the chip's lifetime is reached.

Comment: Excellent answer! one thing to note is that neither SPIFFS nor FATFS are entirely power-failure-safe on ESP chips. I think `littlefs` should be, but it's currently only available as a third party.

Comment: Right. Well, SPIFFS makes a rather good effort of failing safely on power loss, at least. FAT doesn't even try, AFAIK.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the 4,000 byte limit is per string, or for all strings?  I need to store several strings, and 4,000 bytes would be OK if it were the per-string limit, but not if it were the limit for all of them combined.

Comment: @OutstandingBill - it's per string. You can store as much string data as your partition can hold :)